# process finished with exit code 0 in a bot's code

Tags: python, bots, error-code

i'm trying to build a bot and I think it's okay, and also pycharm gives me back the exit code 0, so it's right but the real deal is that it don't give me back the bot or else, just "process finished with exit code 0". Anyone knows why?

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarket.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
        self.params: {
            'start': '1',
            'limit': '100',
            'convert': 'USD'
        }
        self.headers = {
            'Accepts': 'application/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'b8ee0ea1-ae9b-44ab-9132-02e6e5430eb1'
        }

        def fetchCurrenciesData(self):
            r = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params).json()
            return r['data']
            currencies = []
            for currency in r['data']:
                if currency['quote']['USD']['percent_change_in_1Hour'] > 1:
                    currencies.append(
                        currency['symbol']
                    )
                    print(currencies)
```

Comment: Does your code actually run the bot? Apart from writing the class you'll also need to write some code to use it, e.g. something like `Bot().fetchCurrenciesData()`.

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: Yes it is the full code

Comment: Czaporka can you be more clear, please? Maybe with an example, i'd be so glad

Answer (score 0):

Put the function `fetchCurrenciesData()` outside of the `__init__()` function then try to call it